# Load 1000 record to UITableView with Paging

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How do I load 1000 record to `UITableView` with Paging and load on scrolling ?

Comment: Why do you want to page the content? How are you getting the content / how is it stored?

Answer (score 0):

Paging in tables is something tricky in iOS.

First of all decide how many rows do you want to display in one page.
According to that load every records when you travel through paging. This will help to work better execution of application.
I recommend you to fist create a `UITableView` in `UIView`.

Then add two button at the top of tableview. At first show 1-10 records.
When you click next button show records like 10 to 20 in table view.
and when you click previous butoon show records from 1-10. 
Here you have take a variable which counts the no of records displayed.

Hope it will help you.